# How can I keep TCP packets from being dropped?

Tags: java, node.js, tcp, network-programming, udp

I'm creating a program on my Android phone to send the output of the camera to a server on the same network.  Here is my Java code:

```
camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 3000);
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            out.write(data);
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        }
```

The server is a NodeJS server:

```
time = 0

video_server.on 'connection', (socket) ->
    buffer = []
    socket.on 'data', (data) ->
            buffer.push data
    socket.on 'end', ->
            new_time = (new Date()).getTime()
            fps = Math.round(1000/(new_time - time)*100)/100
            console.log fps
            time = new_time

            stream = fs.createWriteStream 'image.jpg'
            stream.on 'close', ->
                    console.log 'Image saved.', fps
            stream.write data for data in buffer
            stream.end()
```

My terminal is showing about 1.5 fps (5 Mbps).  I know very little about network programming, but I do know there should definitely be enough bandwidth.  Each image is 640x480x1.5 at 18 fps, which is about 63 Mbps.  The local network should easily be able to handle this, but my debugger in Android is giving me a lot of "Connection refused" messages.

Any help on fixing my bad network practices would be great.  (I'll get to image compression in a little bit -- but right now I need to optimize this step).

Comment: Why do you keep opening and closing TCP connections?

Comment: There is no evidence here that TCP packets are being dropped at all, and 'connection refused' has nothing whatsoever to do with bandwidth or with dropped packets.  Your code pointlessly accumulates the received image in memory before writing any of it to a file, which wastes both time and space.

Comment: @EJP, that's not a very friendly or helpful reply.  I already said I didn't know much about good network practices so I was seeking to learn a little bit.  As for accumulating the code in memory then writing it to a file -- that was not part of my question at all.  My actual code does image analysis and processing.  Does it make any sense that I would rewrite the same image file over and over?  No, it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, To simplify my post.  Questions on here with too much code normally don't get answers.  Ideally I would create one connection with header bytes indicating a new frame, but I didn't think that would affect the throughput in any significant way.

Comment: @Nick I am correcting the misconceptions expressed in your title and your assertion about 'connect'. What would be both 'helpful' and to the point would be stating what *problem* you are experiencing, rather than your guesswork about what the causes are and how to eliminate them. You have equally missed the point about the images. You don't need it all in memory before writing any of it to a file: you can read or write *N* bytes at a time, for any convenient *N*, say 8192; and you don't need a new connection per frame either, as others have noted.

Comment: Do you know that your phone can transfer faster than 5mbps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've designed the system so that it has to do many times more work than it should have to do. You're requiring a connection to be built up and torn down for each frame transferred. That is not only killing your throughput, but it can also run you out of resources.

With a sane design, all that would be required to transfer a frame is to send and receive the frame data. With your design, for each frame, a TCP connection has to be built up (3 steps), the frame data has to be sent and received, and the TCP connection has to be torn down. Worse, the receiver cannot know it has received all of the frame data until the connection shutdown occurs. So this cannot be hidden in the background.

Design a sane protocol and the problems will go away.

Comment: Okay, so if I have a steady stream of image data through one TCP connection, is that the best I can do in terms of throughput?  Or is there some sort of network analysis (MTU optimization?) that I should perform?  Thanks for the good answer by the way.

Comment: You'll need some a header so the reader will know when it has a complete frame. I recommend assembling the header and frame data into a single buffer so you can send it with one call to `write`. In the server, you'll need to loop calling read until you have a complete frame. You can loop until you read a complete header, then loop until you read the complete frame data (being careful not to over-read), then go on to read the next header after processing that frame. You have to be aggressive in the writing because otherwise you can cause bad Nagling/delayed ack. No such issues in the receiver.

Comment: +1 because @DavidSchwartz is just about spot-on here.  Using TCP connect/disconnect for message-framing is just about the worst protocol imaginable and totally dire for demands such as video, especially over high-latency wireless networks.  You need a sane protocol, now!

Answer (score 1):

Is this working at all?  I do not see where you are binding to port 3000 on the server.

In any case, if this is a video stream, you should probably be using UDP instead of TCP.  In UDP, packets may be dropped, but for a video stream this will probably not be noticeable.  UDP communication requires much less overhead than TCP due to the number of messages exchanged.  TCP contains a lot of "acking" to make sure each piece of data reaches its destination;  UDP doesn't care, and thus sends less packets.  In my experience, UDP based code is generally less complex than TCP based code.

_ryan

Comment: Yeah, it works.  I left out portions of code and modified bits that were irrelevant to the question.  I'll read up on UDP and give it a shot.  Is there something I should know about maximizing throughput with UDP?  (I know I'll possibly need to re-order packets and handle dropped ones on the other end.)

Comment: UDP makes use of a standard ethernet frame size known as the maximum transmission unit (MTU) which is usally ~1500 bytes.  If you can compress the video such that the frames are within this size, you can have a very simple protocol where you throw packets from one end and catch them at the other, without regard for dropped packets or reordering or any other unnecessary complexity. With UDP, a single read operation can read an entire ethernet frame of size MTU, resulting in smaller, simpler code and better performance.